# Clarification on "if" statement - Digital Clock Tutorial C#

Tags: c#

I am building a digital clock in C# after watching a tutorial. The code in the tutorial I need help understanding looks like this:

```
if (hh < 10) {
    time += "0" + hh;
}
else {
    time += hh;
}
time += ":";
```

Can anyone explain to me why hh < 10? Should it not be at least 12?

My end  game is to make a timer that starts at 9am and stops at 5pm. Ongoing applications under development. Looking at time money management.

Comment: ps, "time" is a string, hh is an int representing the DateTime function.

Comment: The purpose of that code snippet seems to prefix a `'0'` character for any hour lower than `10` for representation. Nothing to do with the 12 hour clock cycle.

Comment: Mmm, that explains why the clock always displays the time in a 12-hour cycle. Do you have any idea how to pull a DateTime int value in an if statement?

Comment: If this isn't your code, then I'm afraid this is off-topic. It's also off-topic, because we can't help with explaining how code works: we only review concrete, working code, which the OP already understands. See the [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for more information.

Comment: Never mind. I fixed the solution using two different int values for time then comparing these with an if statement.

Comment: @SamuelJosling Please delete your question, it's blatantly _off-topic_ here.

Comment: Can people please stop upvoting that clearly _off-topic_ questiion. You go in the way of moderation and curation of this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Codereview. 
As I can see you are having troubles understanding the line that adds a `"0"` in front of `hh`. Let's say `hh` is `9`. Then, as `9` **is smaller than 10**, `time` will be `"09"`, **if hh is `"10"`, or greater, it won't add that `"0"` at the beginning**.
 After that (`time += ":"`), the program will add a `":"` which would represent the hours in the clock and a `":"` character afterwards, like `"10:"` or `"09:"`. 
So, When it adds the minutes, the algorithm will use a similar `if` statement, like this:

```
if (hh < 10) {
    time += "0" + hh;
}
else {
    time += hh;
}
time += ":";
if (mm < 10) {
    time += "0" + mm;
}
else {
    time += mm;
}
```

at the end the `time` that will be shown, will look something like `"09:09"`, and such.